# jQuery AJAX Request return XML

Tags: jquery, xml, ajax

```
<suggestions>
<user>
<![CDATA[ Chris ]]>
</user>
<user>
<![CDATA[ Christina ]]>
</user>
</suggestions>
```

and the js part

```
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: 'index.php/Suggest/',
                dataType: 'xml',
                data: {username: username},
                success: function(data) {
                    $(data).find('suggestions').each(function(){
                        if ($(this).find('user').text()) {
                            $('#container').html('<div>' + $(this).find('user').text() + '</div>');
                        }
                    });
                },
                error: function(request, status, error) {
                    // will also occur when the user toggles a window and instantly clicks on a link, so don't alert anything
                }
            });
```

inserts

```
<div>ChrisChristina</div>
```

but I want

```
<div>Chris</div> <div>Christina</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `append` instead of `html` if you want to add all users:

```
    $(data).find('suggestions').each(function(){
        $(this).find('user').each(function(){
            $('#container').append('<div>' + $(this).text() + '</div>');
        });
    });
```

Comment: `success: function(data) {
      $('#cChatMenuContentContainer').empty();
      $(data).find('user').each(function(){
       $('#cChatMenuContentContainer').append('<div>' + $(this).text() + '</div>');
      });
     },` works for me, thx

Answer (score 1):

I think it iterates over the `suggestions`. Instead it should iterate over `user`. Here is the working code:

```js
var response = ""+
"<suggestions>" +
"<user>" + 
"<![CDATA[ Chris ]]>" +
"</user>" + 
"<user>" + 
"<![CDATA[ Christina ]]>" + 
"</user>" + 
"</suggestions>";

// This is using the JSFiddle "echo" interface
$.post("/echo/xml/", {"xml": response}, function(data) {
    $(data).find('user').each(function(i, user){
        $("#container").append($("<div>").text($(user).text()));
    });
});​
```

You can view it [live on JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vynYa/)

Answer (score 0):

You will need to iterate over each `user` element. When using `text()` method on more than one element, all the text is returned but method has no way to identify to add spaces.

```
$(data).find('suggestions').each(function() {
    var $user=$(this).find('user');
      /* use length to check if user elements exist*/
     if($user.length){
          var user=$user.map(function(){
            return $(this).text();
          }).get().join(' ')

        $('#container').append('<div>' + user + '</div>');
    }
});
```